# git2consul does not import configuration from git

Tags: git, consul

I'm using [git2consul](https://github.com/Cimpress-MCP/git2consul) in order to push configuration from a local/github repository to my consul KV store.

When using default configuration for git2consul:

```js
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "repos" : [{
    "name" : "sample_configuration",
    "url" : "https://github.com/ryanbreen/git2consul_data.git",
    "branches" : ["dev"],
    "hooks": [{
      "type" : "polling",
      "interval" : "1"
    }]
  }]
}
```

uploading the configuration to consul & starting git2consul I see no K/V imported besides dev.ref
and i see no git2consul process running on the linux machine.

Can someone assist?

Answer (score 0):

check if you have keys store at KV or not using below query:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/?recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'you see no process running' - do you mean, nothing happens? Are there any errors?

Make sure you are running git2consul on the same box that your Consul Client agent is running.

If possible, start your Consul Client with the -ui flag and log into the Key/Value page - you should see a folder sample_configuration, then the name of your branch, then any other folders, and finally your .properties file with each property key value from the file.

Also try feeding the file to the command by running `git2consul --config-file yourConfigFile.json`

I do not believe you will see individual properties loading in the command line console when running the process...